# How to fix 'geom_path: each group consists of only one observation. do you need to adjust the group aesthetic'? in R

Tags: r

This is the question:

Using a single pipe function, create a new variable called
`year_season` that pastes together year and season (paste(year, season, sep="-")).
Then, summarize the average, minimum, and maximum number of bikes
and construct a plot with `year_season` on the x-axis and number
of bikes on the y-axis. Show three lines (geom_line): one for the
minimum, one for the maximum, and one for the average value.
Somehow differentiate the max/min from the average value (you can use
linetype, color, or line size to do this; completely up to you).

Note: In order for this to work, the first line of your plot needs to
be this (without the quotes): 'ggplot(aes(year_season, count_avg, group=1)) +'

This is the code i've done but I'm not sure why this is wrong and why i'm not getting a plot:

```
bikes %>%
mutate(year_season = paste(year,season, sep="-")) %>%
summarize (avg_bikes=mean(count), min_bikes=min(count), 
max_bikes=max(count)) %>%
ggplot(aes(year_season,avg_bikes,group=1))+
geom_line(aes(avg_bikes, group=avg_bikes))+
geom_line(aes(min_bikes, group=min_bikes))+
geom_line(aes(max_bikes, group=max_bikes))
```

Comment: What error did you get? Moreover it seems that you did not ```group_by``` any variable so your are not really summarizing anything. I think that you want to do ```group_by(year_season)``` before summarizing.

Comment: We don't have your data and can't see your output, so without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we don't know what's going on. This looks like your homework, though, so I'm guessing you probably have some class materials on using `ggplot2`, which generally takes long-shaped data and maps variables to aesthetics like color